# Drush command needs higher bootstrap level - Pantheon Drush Alias Setup

Tags: drush, bootstrapping

I just setup pantheon for one of my websites. So far I've done the following and the site works fine:

Version Drush: 5.3
Local Dev: Ubuntu 12.04

1. Git clone the repo to my local desktop
2. Copy the pantheon.aliases.php file to the .drush directory at ~/home

Now when i do a **drush @pan.chouse.dev pm-list** I get the following error.

> ```
> ~/websites/pan-chouse$ drush @pan.chouse.dev pm-list
>
> Command pm-list needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need    [error]
> to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run thiscommand.
>
> The drush command 'pm-list' could not be executed.                       [error]
> The directory /home/drupalpro/websites/pan-chouse does not contain a     [error]
> valid Drupal installation
> ```

I also did a **drush @pan.chouse.dev status** and I get this:

> ~/websites/pan-chouse$ drush @pan.chouse.dev status  PHP
>   configuration   : 
>   /srv/bindings/a59cd0c1631747ef8cda2b5e88fc5124/php.ini
>                           /srv/bindings/a59cef8cda2b5e88fc5124/php.ini    Drush
>   version       :  5.10.0
>   Drush               : 
>   /srv/bindings/a59cd8cda2b5e88fc5124/drushrc.
>   configuration          php

I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong as it should technically work.

Comment: What does `drush sa @pan.chouse.dev` say?  It looks like your alias is empty.

Comment: nvm it works.. it shows this... http://prntscr.com/4u81at

Comment: Do you have settings.php in place ?

Comment: yea i just copied another settings.php files into the default folder... it still doesnt show any response. but when i go outside of the drupal folder.. i get a response from pantheon, but it shows that the default theme is "garland", but i have "omega" as the default theme... see here: http://prntscr.com/4u9yzt

Comment: Does your alias specify a bunch of additional params? Here's one of my Pantheon aliases:
`$aliases['mysite.test'] = array(
'root' => '.',
'uri' => 'test.mysite.gotpantheon.com',
'remote-host' => 'appserver.test.long-id.drush.in',
'remote-user' => 'test.long-id,
'ssh-options' => '-p 2222 -o "AddressFamily inet"',`

Comment: yea i have all of that.. see: http://prntscr.com/4ui6m7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so this is how i solved it after 4 days of trying... the docs and support techs on pantheon are not clear which has lead to this confusion and im sure many others too.

To get Drush aliases to work you have to have a **settings.php** file in the sites/default folder. **BUT!** when we use pantheon, we all git clone the codebase to our local. So we all assume that we needed it in our local drupal setup that we cloned which is not the case.

You have to have the EMPTY **settings.php** file on the PANTHEON servers! In order to get it there, you have to switch your account to SFTP mode from GIT. I then logged in to the server via the terminal. Just copy and paste the cli command they give you on the info box.

Once you get inside, you need to goto this folder:

**code/sites/default**

Then I upload an empty settings.php file taken from default.settings.php.

This is what you should see once setup properly:

[image]

Comment: The need for a settings.php in order to enable Drush aliases to work is fully documented in the Pantheon helpdesk article located here: http://helpdesk.getpantheon.com/customer/portal/articles/411388

Answer (score 4):

While sites on Pantheon don't require a settings.php file in order to serve web requests, due to the fact that database credentials are dynamically injected, they will still need a settings.php configuration file present in order to enable the remote execution of Drush commands. With Drush 5 installed locally, there is [unexpected behavior with Pantheon aliases run from inside a local Drupal docroot](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/313). In addition, the `--strict=0` option needs to be appended to most commands when using Drupal 6 on your local dev environment.

Source: [Drush error “Could not find a Drupal settings.php file” or missing system information from status](http://helpdesk.getpantheon.com/customer/portal/articles/411388-drush-command-line-utility#settings-missing)

Comment: that didnt work.. did it outside of the drupal folder too. see here: http://prntscr.com/4ui78a

Comment: It didn't work because you need a `settings.php` file in your `/code/sites/default/` directory in order to run drush commands on Pantheon aliases. Make a copy of `default.settings.php` and call it `settings.php` and you will have great success.

Comment: nope that didnt work, see here: http://prntscr.com/4uvc4c

Comment: You need to put the settings.php file in your code directory on Pantheon.

Comment: but wouldnt that overwrite the existing one on the pantheon servers? how would i go about doing that?

Comment: ok just uploaded by switching to sftp mode on the dashboard. it was git mode previously. I then sftp into the server and uploaded a settings.php file to code/sites/default --- http://prntscr.com/4uxcnk   ---- and i tried it again ... http://prntscr.com/4uxdjq --- Still doesnt work... now i can't even delete the file. what can i be doing wrong?

Comment: ok got it! had to do it thru the cli